# Understanding the act of banning

Tags: ethics, political-philosophy, moral-skepticism

(I'm new to Philosophy Stack Exchange so let me know if I'm not wording things properly, if I have to improve my question, etc.)

I want to understand why humans always find a way to "ban" each other or at least make one person (or a group of people) exiled. In the bible, for example, God banned Adam and Eve from the Garden of Eden because of their sins. God also banned Satan from Heaven and sent him down to Hell.

In the bible, God is all-powerful. He holds the power to decide what's right or wrong... and in the case of Adam and Eve, they were wrong so banishment was "justified" in that context (note that this is not my belief... i'm just trying to understand what message the bible is intending to give).

However, banishment has happened all throughout human history. What's interesting is that humans are fallible creatures that don't always get to decide right vs. wrong for every situation (often times, people disagree with what's right and what's wrong).

So isn't that problematic? Like today, for instance, there are refugees being forced out of their lands. There are laws like Trump's travel ban that creates the exiled group of people. Is this right or wrong? Can we determine that? Does it sound immoral in a way?

And there are number of people who accept this which is why it's happening. Clearly these forms of banishing and/or exiling are supported by many.

Comment: God is like a forum moderator on a power trip. But ok, I'll say something serious. Man is a social animal. Separation from the tribe is a powerful punishment that does not inflict physical pain; in fact it doesn't even say the person is wrong. Just that they can't live with the rest of us anymore. It's a social decision made by social beings. Also it gives great return and redemption stories. Ben-Hur for example. Makes for great drama. Humans love drama.

Comment: I have noticed that *anything* can sound immoral in a way, if you phrase it right.  There's a famous quote to that end attributed to Cardinal Richelieu: "If one would give me six lines written by the hand of the most honest man, I would find something in them to have him hanged." You can also phrase anything to sound moral.  That's what defense lawyers do for a living (well, part of what they do).  Particular cases like Trump's travel ban are *notoriously* complicated.  The Politics.SE has some good discussion on it.

Comment: welcome to philosophy.SE. I'm not sure how is a question for philosophy. Are you trying to obtain knowledge about how humans function socially, what constitutes banishment, how banishment regulates social constructions and collective intentionality, or, are you looking for a sociological, biological or anthropological explanation? Are you looking for an ethical explanation or justification which explains the biblical deity to you?

Comment: Exile of males is common in all higher mammals.  It is likely an evolutioary mechanism for keeping healthy gene pools. Of course in modern post nomadic humans it is oddly perverse.